# Any IRC clients with VI key binds?

Tags: linux, irc, vi

Is there any IRC client that supports VI keys? The ''obvious'' script VimIRC is and has been broken for so long it's not even funny.

Do you know any IRC clients on Linux, GUI or Curses, that provides some of that nice vi usability?

Or could some of the existing clients be scripted to use? Irssi, XChat, even ERC would do?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. I use [`vim_mode.pl`](https://github.com/shabble/irssi-scripts/tree/master/vim-mode) with
   [`irssi`](http://irssi.org/) (in GNU `screen`) and
   am extremely satisfied with the
   combination.

   For anyone who doesn't know `Irssi`,
   it's terminal-based and there is no
   GUI available or planned. While this
   may put some people off, it makes
   for a great combination with GNU
   `screen`, and allows you to keep
   your connection while being logged
   out: Always a good thing to have for
   IRC and its erratic response times.

   The current version of `vim_mode` is
   already pretty sophisticated, has
   registers, custom mappings and lots
   of other stuff, and it's still being
   developed.

   To use `vim_mode`'s `ex` mode,
   you'll need the [`uberprompt.pl`](https://github.com/shabble/irssi-scripts/blob/master/prompt_info/uberprompt.pl)
   script from
   [`irssi-scripts/prompt_info`](https://github.com/shabble/irssi-scripts/tree/master/prompt_info)
   (same developers).

   The most up-to-date documentation is
   in the `.pl` file itself. If you
   have further questions or
   suggestions, the developers (and a
   few of us lowly users) hang out on
   `#irssi_vim`/Freenode and are
   generally very friendly and
   responsive.
2. An alternative solution would be to use the unixy bare-bones [`ii`](http://tools.suckless.org/ii/) IRC client by the [suckless](http://suckless.org/) community with Vim itself.

   `ii` creates a directory structure in the file system and places FIFOs for channels and server messages that can be written to and read from.

   On the `ii` page, you can find a link to [a working setup](http://nion.modprobe.de/blog/archives/440-Using-the-ii-irc-client.html) that uses `multitail` for split windows, Vim for entry, and shell scripts and `screen` for glue.

   Multitail can be configured to get (non-dynamic) highlighting for the IRC logs, and if you'd buffer the logs, you can use Vim's 'complete' option to get dynamic word completion from them.

Comment: Oh dear peth. You made me so happy. I was an avid irssi user, and I *did* actually once try to provide modality to irssi by binding a mass of keys, but I realized it wouldn't work well by any metric. Guess I were wrong. :)

Comment: The `ii` mode would be quite perfect *if* I got vim somehow to do `tail -f` characteristics. But nothing usable has come around. TailBundle for instance ceases action after a while and so on... It would be perfect to get buffer word completion and omni completion for nicks, and vim's highlighting for the log. And one buffer per IRC channel. Wouldn't that be grand. I'm investigating to vim_mode.pl so perhaps it fills the needs better. Because irssi takes care of many issues that should otherwise be implemented (eg. splitlong, away toggle, ...)

Comment: as much as I wanted to have real vim completion, that kind of tricky tweaking would be too much for me. Now that I've adopted Twirssi, leaving irssi has become not that big an option. Luckily vim_mode is excellent as is. I've been tweaking with extra completion keys (can have both `<Tab>` and `<C-n>` to do different kinds of completion now), but haven't written a buffer completion function yet.

Answer (score 1):

Now that Emacs has more than decent Vi-key emulation package, Evil, ERC is a very viable solution for this. After a little tuning, chatting using ERC and Evil can be very vim experience.

Answer (score 0):

Vim itself has an [IRC plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=931).

Comment: VimIRC is so hopelessly broken I thought it was obvious not to mention it.